# Is it possible to configure MySQL logging so that it only reports queries that were rolled back?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, innodb, rollback

I have an [intermittent bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107850/why-would-magento-fail-to-save-a-customer-after-generating-an-id) that I'm trying to track down, and I'd like to capture only MySQL queries that fail resulting in a rollback.  I don't want a full [general query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html) or [binary](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html) log because there would be millions of entries in the haystack to sort through.

Something like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199812/logging-erroneous-queries-only-on-sql-server) except for MySQL would be perfect.

TIA,
JD

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL it is very difficult (or maybe impossible). You can do it in PHP. If you don't use low functions like `mysql_query` and you use high methods like ->query(), you can add logic to theirs. If query failed (return false for example), add it to log. Sorry for my english.

Note for Zend_DB:

```
class My_DB extends Zend_DB {
    public function insert($data) {
        try {
            parent::insert($data);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // put $e->getMessage() to log
        }
    }
}
```

You can overwrite different methods, such as update, query and others...

Comment: Thanks @garvey - I'd rather not introduce code to trap the error since this is a production system, but it may be the best answer.  Magento does have an ORM layer via Zend_DB, so it could be done there.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but the utility `mysqlbinlog` can extract data from the binary log.

See: the user comments in this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log.html
And this page: http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/mysql-dml-stats-per-table-2009-09-09/

Here's the [official documentation for mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html), which might help you get the info you need.

Comment: Thanks @johan - I don't see how the ronaldbradford link is helpful, am I missing something? are you suggesting that I could include "rollback" or something as a regex string?

Comment: @Jonathan, yes that's exactly what I'm suggesting.